# Get Features in heatmap openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to get all features when I click on heat map in openlayers 3...It is possible or not? How to count the features in heat map and give heat map total count features label? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Openlayers3 can do this easily,You can use getFeatures() to get all the features.

```
var features = heatlayer.getSource().getFeatures()
alert('count: '+features.length);
```

This method returns an array containing all the features,so you can use length to count.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>heatlayer count example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .map {
        max-width: 566px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });
      
      var heatlayer = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
        source: new ol.source.Vector(),
        blur: parseInt(14),
        radius: parseInt(8)
      });
      
            var adddata = [[104.807799,30.232233],[106.803599,31.233225]];
      //addfeature
      for(var i = 0;i < adddata.length ; i++){
        var feature = new ol.Feature({
          geometry:new ol.geom.Point([adddata[i][0],adddata[i][1]])
        });
        heatlayer.getSource().addFeature(feature);
    }
      

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster,heatlayer],
        target: 'map',
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
          attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
            collapsible: false
          })
        }),
        view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
          center:[104.07, 30.7],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });

      map.on('click', function(event){
        var features = heatlayer.getSource().getFeatures()
        alert('count: '+features.length);
      });
       
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this in ol6. but its not working. no heatmap is showing